# Get scanned Data using MC40 android device

Tags: java, android

I am making an App for the MC40 Motorola Android device.  I want to be able to use the device to scan a barcode and get the data to be used elsewhere.  I do not want to always have to use an EditText to capture the scan data.  I want some kind of call back function to take the scan and manipulate the data that was just scanned.  Does anyone know of a way to do this?  I have been searching for days now.

Comment: Did you have a look to http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-create-a-barcode-reader/

Comment: Yes I did.  It did not help as ZXing does not use the scanner built into the MC40.  If it ZXing can use the built in scanner, I am not sure how to.  So maybe the answer I need is a way to link the built in scanner with ZXing.

Answer (score 0):

To integrate your application with the HW Barcode Scanner available in the Motorola Solution (now Zebra Technologies) MC40, you can use the [Symbol EMDK for Android](https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/community/android/emdk).

Using the [DataCapture API](https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/docs/DOC-2185) you can get an Intent from DataWedge with the barcode information, as explained in this tutorial.

To programmatically setup the DataWedge profile, you can use the [Profile Manager API](https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/docs/DOC-2991).

If you need a finer control of the Barcode scanning activities you can integrate directly with the [Barcode API](https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/docs/DOC-2659).